# Does Trino/Presto support PL/SQL?

Tags: presto, trino

Does Trino/Presto support PL/SQL type programming, i.e. data returned by one sql statement can be passed on to another sql statement for processing? Does it support For loop, while loop etc

Comment: I don't know [tag:trino] but according to this [link](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/call.html), there is at least some way to call procedures that could implement this paradigm.

Comment: @sanitizedUser, the CALL procedures are connector specific (For ex: Oracle database). I am not sure whether we can add user defined procedures